# Related Customs posts

Tags: posts

Maybe someone can help to make related posts with custom posts type? I am stuck with that...
Code is here: https://pastebin.com/zRVjuMBn

**For example:**

**We are in current post:**

ID  |  title | cust_category |  cust_names |  cust_settings

1   |  X1    | cat1, cat3    |  name8      |  set1, set5

**And we have customs posts:**

ID  |  title | cust_category |  cust_names |  cust_settings

2   |  X4    | cat1          |  name9      |  set2

3   |  X1    | cat1, cat3    |  name9      |  set5

4   |  X8    | cat12         |  name12     |  set12

**So related posts to current post (ID = 1) will be:**

ID 3 and ID 2.

- ID3 is the most related, because it has the same values - X1, cat1, set5 (related 3 values).
- ID 2 is also related by one value - cat1.

***Or you can see this explanation in image:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

P.S. In this project I use ONLY the same custom post type. No simple posts and other. Just "custom_post_name" customs posts. Nothing else.
I am trying to make it work about few weeks. Please help me. As I understand I need only a good query and that is it. I am very beginner in WP.